# How to run custom HTML/JS/GSAP inside Visual Composer/Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gsap

I am attempting to use custom JS and custom html within VC, but am having trouble correctly calling the JS code.
My goal is to be able to use the Greensock Animation Platform.  I am starting with simple code to get this working.
In Visual Composer, I have setup a "Raw HTML" element, and also a "Raw JS" element.
When I launch the page, the HTML shows up correctly, but most of my scripts don't execute.
The default script that is provided by VC works:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Enter your js here!" ); </script>
```

However, this simple script fails:

```
<script> function onReady() {
console.log('Here')
}
</script>
```

Also, a simple GSAP script fails:

```
<script type=​"text/​javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type=​"text/​javascript">
    TweenMax.set('#slide3', {opacity: 0});
}
</script>
```

My current attempt is here:
https://themilkmob.org/zgsaptest01/

A screengrab of the backend editor:[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine this can be improved, but with help from someone on the Greensock Fourm, I've been able to get this to work:
If there is a page element with ID "slide3", this code (in a "RawJS" VC element) will set it to 50% transparent:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    TweenMax.set('#slide3', {opacity: 0.5});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What I think , we would have to add this: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    js code here
});                                                                                                                  Then our script works fine.. I also run my js code same way in visual composer.